# NetInfo has been removed from React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Before you try to automatically delete this as a duplicate, hear me out.
I have spent all day googling this and trying everything.

My project is a React Native app using Expo.

Recently, when I was adding some packages to get testing working, I started to get this error:

`Invariant Violation: NetInfo has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/netinfo' instead of 'react-native'.  See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo`

As people suggested, I tried searching through my Node Modules folder for any old style imports of the netInfo package, but there were none.
I have tried rolling back my node modules to a previous state from and older commit by deleting the node_modules folder, replacing package.json with an older setup that I know worked and `npm i` to reinstall.

I need something else to try.

Here is my package.json that I know worked in the past, but is giving me the error anyway

```json
{

  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.7",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "@redux-offline/redux-offline": "^2.6.0-expo.0",
    "expo": "^42.0.3",
    "expo-app-loading": "1.1.2",
    "expo-location": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-sqlite": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.11.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"

  },
  "private": true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Recently, when I was adding some packages to get testing working

Since NetInfo is not used directly in your code, I imagine that one of the packages you recently added is still attempting to access NetInfo via React Native.

First you'll need to determine which package is causing this. Then either update it to a newer version which imports NetInfo from `@react-native-community/netinfo`, or remove the package entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To clarify. I have already rolled back to before any of those new packages were added. I have reinstalled my node modules half a dozen times now.

I have changed the vscode search restrictions to allow me to search in the node modules folder and I searched for "Import { NetInfo", "Import NetInfo" and many other permutations. I swear to you, It's not there.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Remove Redux Offline, and all of it's imports. @redux-offline/redux-offline: "^2.6.0-expo.0",

Wow, this was a day and a half of work duzy. It was weird too, because I tried going way back to an old commit and rebuilding there, but I would still get the error. So on a whim, I downloaded my repo from github, then went to and old commit, installed the packages, and it worked! Still have no idea why my original local repo wouldn't.

So I split the difference between the working commit and the broken commit until I found the source of the problem, and the culprit was @redux-offline/redux-offline: "^2.6.0-expo.0",

No idea why it was causing the issue, maybe I just have it set up wrong, I hand't gotten it working anyway, so I'm removing it for now till I have time to do it right.